# Query InfluxDB for specific hours each day which fall across different days because of UTC and my time zone

Tags: time, intervals, grafana, influxdb

I am querying influxdb to produce a graph in grafana. Influxdb contains kW solar production with a timestamp every 5 seconds. I want to aggregate solar production from 4PM to 9PM every day. In UTC this becomes 2300 to 0400. I can do 2300 to 0000 and separately 0000 to 0400 but I dont know how to add these together with grafana. Or it would be nice to do 2300-0400 in one query. Here are my 2 queries for 2300 to 0000 and 0000 to 0400:

```
SELECT first("integral") FROM (  SELECT integral("kW",1h) FROM "solar"  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04T23:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(1h))  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04T23:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(24h,23h)
```

```
SELECT first("integral") FROM (  SELECT integral("kW",1h) FROM "solar"  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-05' GROUP BY time(4h))  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-05' GROUP BY time(24h)
```

Update:
The following works for the 1h of the time span that I want:

```
SELECT first("integral") FROM (  SELECT integral("kW",1h) FROM "solar"  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04 16:00:00' GROUP BY time(1h))  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04 16:00:00' GROUP BY time(24h,16h) tz('America/Los_Angeles')
```

however, if I increase the timespan to 2h, it returns the wrong result:

```
SELECT first("integral") FROM (  SELECT integral("kW",1h) FROM "solar"  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04 16:00:00' GROUP BY time(2h))  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04 16:00:00' GROUP BY time(24h,16h) tz('America/Los_Angeles')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the timezone `TZ` clause https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-time-zone-clause

You could also start at 23:00 group by `time(5h)` (which would basically include data from next day and save it at 23:00 o'clock for the current day) and then take the last (instead of first) result for a 24 hour period.

So something like (notice additional `as kW` alias)

```
SELECT last("kW") FROM (  SELECT integral("kW",1h) as kW FROM "solar"  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04T23:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(5h))  WHERE TIME >'2019-10-04T23:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(24h)
```

Or do the above + TZ.
Not sure what exactly would work in your use case.

Comment: I am not sure time(5h) works over multiple days. I dont think it matters if you are taking first or last, since 5h doesnt divide into 24h. So for the first day it might work, but then for the next day the "first" or "last" time period is different.

Comment: Please see update above. Using the timezone spec, I am able to return 1h of the time span that I want, but if I increase it to 2h then it doesnt return the right value. Confused.

Comment: Regarding  you first comment, it works over whatever period of time you give it so it should include data from next day but you are right that a period of time of 5h does not fit well into 24h, I somehow convinced myself that it does ...  
Regarding your second comment, it depends on your data to some extent. Could it be that you have to adjust the integral to also work over a 2h period if you group by 2h?

Comment: The integral is over an hour to get kWh. I have a feeling its because it translates to Z and then it goes across two days again. I ll double check that for an earlier period of time all these different timespans would work as long as they dont go across two days. I should probably post on influxdb website somewhere?